# Oracle developer suite 6i and Oracle XE database.

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle forms and database. I installed oracle developer suite 6i and XE database on windows machine. Using Sql developer, I am able to connect to the database and execute all the query against HR schema. When using the PLUS80w.exe from developer suite to connect, I get incorrect user and password error. Can I some one tell what could be the possible error?

P.S. Both the tnsnames.ora are identical.

Comment: you have tagged both oracle11g and oracle10g, but you say you're using XE - are you on 11gXE or 10gXE? If 11g, passwords are case-sensitive on the database side, but PLUS80w.exe will assume they are not, so it will send the password in all-uppercase. Change the password to uppercase to find out.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeffrey. I updated the password to uppercase, tried connecting, PLUS80W.exe stops responding. I am able to connect to Oracle 9i database through VPN. It is working fine. Could be compatibility issue?

Comment: I don't know - but connecting from a 8 client to an 11g db is unsupported. A reinstall might help, but that's just a wild guess. Why did you install such an old version of dev suite anyway? If you're just starting out I'd recommend Dev Suite 11g.

Comment: By the way, please confirm the actual versions of the software you're using. You still have 11g and 10g tagged.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I mainly need to have oracle forms and reports(We are using 6i at my work). I thought it may be better to start with 6i. 11g is installed on my machine and at work we have 9i database. I also tried installing 11g dev suite on my old laptop, it has serious performance issue. so down graded the version.

Comment: If your work is still on Forms 6i + DB 9i then good luck to you :) I'd say you'll be frustrated if you try to learn it on Forms 11g because a lot of things were improved and changed, and when you go back to work you'll feel a bit hamstrung. Also, I'd try using 10gXE for the database in your case, as far as Forms development is concerned 9i and 10g are very similar.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I agree with you. Will install 10g and try. Hope it works.